# How can the line numbers in my stack traces be wrong?

Tags: python-2.7, stack-trace

I have a python (version 2.7.6) program that had been running for a day or two as of last night when it reported some errors. However, the stack traces were blatantly wrong. Pretend my code is like this:

```
def do_A():
    do_some_stuff()
    do_B()

def do_B():
    do_some_IO_that_could_fail()

def do_C():
    if len('abc'):
        do_D()

def do_D():
    do_other_stuff()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_A()
```

The task that can fail did fail, *but my stack trace was like this*:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfile.py", line 16, in <module>
    do_A()
  File "myfile.py", line 9, in do_A
    if len('abc'):
  File "myfile.py", line 13, in do_B
    do_other_stuff()
  CustomFailureException: "The thing that can fail? It failed."
```

In my stack trace, the "in ..." parts are reasonable in that they describe a path that can actually get to the part of my code that has the `CustomFailureException`. The line numbers and the code it shows are consistent (i.e it says line 9 and has the code that's on line 9), but it's the wrong line.

**Does anyone have any clue how this could happen to my stack trace?**

Note: This particular task runs every night, and has been doing so for a while. It normally finishes successfully, but it has failed before and given a normal stack trace. Last night, it consistently failed and consistently gave the same incorrect stack trace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens when you change the source file after the code is running.  The compiled source has line number references to the source code, but the stack traceback fills in the actual source text by reloading the source file.  I think there is some kind of caching as well but that's not relevant here.

So the problem here is just that the source file no longer matches the (compiled) program that is actually running, likely because it was changed after the program started or perhaps they have become out of sync by some more complicated trickery ...

Comment: Looking at the most recent change to my file (thank you Git!) and going down the number of lines that I'd added earlier in the file, I got to  the right line. I guess that I forgot to actually restart my program after I updated the code. Anyway, I was hoping that there was a relatively simple explanation for this bizarre behavior.

Comment: Is there a name for this phenomena or some way to Google more? I am having a related bug (using old versions) despite rerunning Python. Perhaps the issue is with the caching you speak of, but not sure how to Google it

Comment: You haven't given enough information for me to recognise your problem but i seriously doubt any connecting

Comment: ... connection. The caching i mention happens in the python interpreter when it reads source code lines. It cannot persist across runs of the interpreter.