# KeyError when adding to set in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I ran my program in Python 3.4, and it crashed. Stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]

  File [...], line 176, in manual_setup
    gammas.add((name, group_oid))
KeyError: '5733455d-ba37-48c6-b550-8f53b719310c'
```

Here's the code at that line. Never mind what the variables are, just that gammas is a `set`, as you can see:

```
gammas = set()
for group_oid, name, _ in self.tags:
    gammas.add((name, group_oid))
```

By the way,  `name` and `group_oid` are both `str`, but even if they were something unhashable, I'd get a different error.

I'm not excluding the possibility that I have something totally different going on, but before I look into weird causes I haven't even thought of yet, I'd like to know if `set.add` could possibly be throwing `KeyError`. The documentation suggests no. My knowledge of how sets work says it shouldn't. Has anyone out there seen this happen?

I checked to see if `set` was somehow overridden. PyCharm says it's the built-in Python set.

Comment: I agree that `set.add` itself should not raise a `KeyError`. What kind of object is `self.tags`? Any chance it does anything clever like lazy loading entries on iteration?

Comment: To hope to debug this you will need start with a blank file and create a minimal complete and verifiable example that shows this error. Otherwise there this bug can't be reproduced.

Comment: @DanielHepper `self.tags` is a list. To be sure, I'll print out the type just in case, along with `group_oid` and `name`, when I debug.

Comment: @JamesK I'll try putting those exact values into a set once I find the offending ones. Need to run one more time with debug output in that spot.

Comment: Make sure you're looking at the values from the iteration where the error occurs.

Answer (score 4):

The only `set` operations that generate a `KeyError` are `pop` on an empty set and `remove` for an element that isn't in the set. `add` can't generate a `KeyError`.

My first guess would be that this exception is coming from the `__hash__` method of `name` or `group_oid`. Inspecting those objects in a debugger could be informative. There's also the possibility it's coming from an `__eq__` method.

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking on those right now. Will take some more time to run the script to that point again.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, the Python interpreter was outputting the wrong line number and accompanying code for the error. The error was a few lines above. I should've guessed... Maybe I changed the code while it was running ([How can the line numbers in my stack traces be wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33175257/how-can-the-line-numbers-in-my-stack-traces-be-wrong)), but I don't think I did. Anyway, it's not happening anymore.

P.S. I didn't immediately re-run and catch it because the script takes a long time to reach that point again.